# Visual Studio CLR/CLI c++ manipulating values during runtime

Tags: c++, user-interface, clr

I am a complete beginner in c++ although I have considerable experience in Java. I am working on a project for my c++ class and my group and I have decided to make a c++ project that implements a GUI using the CLR windows forms in Visual Studio 2017.

I have created a windows form and it's name is GUI.h and I have added to it a label and a button. Now I can easily manipulate the label through the event handler for the button, however, let's say I want to change the label without using the button.

Here is my main method:

```
void main()
{
Application::EnableVisualStyles();
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
GUI form;
Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Now before the form is run using Application::Run(%form), I can manipulate the label by using:

```
form.label1->Text = "something";
```

However, after the Application::Run(%form) it is no longer possible by adding the same statement under. How can I execute the same statement and make it work after Application::Run(%form)?

Comment: Pretty basic, Application::Run() is a blocking call.  It runs the dispatcher loop that makes the form paint itself and ensures that events like Click run.  It completes when you close the form, the program terminates next.  So of course you won't have anything to look at anymore, any code after Run() executes too late.  You have to put this code in the right spot, somewhere inside the form class.  Following a tutorial or introductory book on winforms programming is advisable, it is a bit too convoluted to give you any real hope of guessing correctly.

Comment: @HansPassant so is it not possible to change the text while it is in Application::Run() without the use of a button?

Comment: That is what I meant, you are doing too much guessing.  If you don't state the exact reason why this label text should change then we can't guess at it either.  The constructor of the form class is the first obvious place to do it.